# Plot with one line for each column and time-series on the x-axis R

Tags: r, ggplot2

You can find my dataset [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B8clGpnMSCjUdTRXNjBNMktkdVE).

From this data, I wish to plot (one line for each):

```
x$y[,1]
x$y[,5]
x$y[,1]+x$y[,5]
```

Therefore, more clearly, in the end, each of the following will be represented by one line:

```
y0, 
z0, 
y0+z0
```

My x-axis (time-series) will be from `x$t`.

I have tried the following, but the time-series variable is problematic and I cannot figure out how I can exactly plot it. My code is:

```
Time <- x$t
X0 <- x$y[,1]
Z0 <- x$y[,5]
X0.plus.Z0 <- X0 + Z0
xdf0 <- cbind(Time,X0,Z0,X0.plus.Z0)
xdf0.melt <- melt(xdf0, id.vars="Time")

ggplot(data = xdf0.melt, aes(x=Time, y=value)) + geom_line(aes(colour=Var2))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error in your code comes from the use of `melt` applied to an object that is not a data.frame. You should modify like this:

```
xdf0 <- cbind.data.frame(Time,X0,Z0,X0.plus.Z0)
xdf0.melt <- reshape2::melt(xdf0, id.vars="Time")
ggplot(data = xdf0.melt, aes(x=Time, y=value)) + geom_line(aes(colour=variable))
```

You don't *have* to go through the `melt` process since you juste have 3 lines to plot, it's fine to plot them separately

```
ggplot(data=xdf0) + aes(x=Time) +
  geom_line(aes(y=X0), col="red") +
  geom_line(aes(y=Z0), col="blue") +
  geom_line(aes(y=X0.plus.Z0))
```

However, you don't get the legend.

A remark about your example: you try to plot values of really different order of magnitude, so you can't really see anything.

Comment: Wow... This really saved me. Thank you!!! Is there a way to add legend (to specify which color represents what) to this plot?

Comment: yes, in fact i modified my answer to adapt your code as well, so it gives the legend

Comment: Great. I see that the remark you have made is actually a very fundamental problem, given that my data is not random data, and is actually meant for a project, therefore proper plotting is very important. I just wonder to know whether it would be possible to plot each variable (y0, z0, y0+z0) on different panels, but all panels composing a whole plot, I know that `zoo` library/function offers this, but would it be possible to also do this using ggplot?

Comment: you can try facetting, with free scale... `ggplot(data = xdf0.melt, aes(x=Time, y=value)) + geom_line() + facet_wrap(~variable, scale="free")`, which is roughly equivalent to the basic `plot.ts(xdf0)`

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
matplot(xdf0, type = 'l')
```

?

Comment: Couldn't be easier than that. Great!!